# How do I run stand-alone Eclipse MAT?

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-profiling

I generated hprof using jmap.

```
sudo ~/jdk/bin/jmap -F -dump:file=app.hprof 5003
```

Now, I am getting OOM / 'Java Heap Space' error while parsing *.hprof in eclipse. I think I need to run it as stand-alone.

How do I run it? any references?

Comment: It looks like newer versions moved these variables into eclipse.ini

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume, you've downloaded [Eclipse MAT in the form of Standalone Eclipse RCP Application](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php). If not - do so now, and extract the archive to a folder that suits you.

You're getting the OOME, because MAT has too few memory available (the heap-dump you're parsing is too big).

To make the heap bigger, edit your `MemoryAnalyzer.ini` file (it should be in your MAT directory), and add the following lines to it:

```
-vmargs
-Xmx2048M
```

The `2048M` means 2 gigabytes of heap space will be available to the JVM. Perhaps 1 gigabyte will be enough for you.

**Note!**
If you are using MAT as an Eclipse plugin, you can probably do the same trick by editing `eclipse.ini` in your Eclipse directory.

Comment: where is MemoryAnalyzer.ini, in eclipse dir? I meant to launch it as stand alone app.

Comment: The amount of heap you'll need is the size of the heap that was dumped plus about 10%. So 2 GB of heap space lets you analyze an almost 2 GB heap.