# Memory leak because of loading a bitmap in a viewholder

Tags: android, listview, memory, bitmap

I use a `viewholde`r to load images for my `listview`. I download and cache images from the server and the `GetImage` interface method is called to load the image from a local path.

The problem is when i use `Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile (_coverImgLocation);` to load the image, i get a memory exception after scrolling in the `listview`. I know that the images have to be loaded at the correct size by calculating the samplesize. In this case it's not needed because the images from the server already have the same size as the `ImageView`s from the rows.

when i load the image like this: `Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)_activity.Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.splash)).Bitmap;` i get no memory exception but ofcourse this is the wrong image...

How can i retrieve the bitmap from the path without having a memory leak?

the `getimage` method in the `viewholder`:

```
public void GetImage(string originalImageLocation,string localImageLocation)
    {
        if (originalImageLocation == _coverImgLocation) 
        {
            int screenWidth = _activity.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
            int imgWidth = screenWidth - (int)ConvertDpToPix (32f);
            int imgHeight = (int)(ConvertDpToPix(206f));

            BundleProgress.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;


            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile (_coverImgLocation); //memoryexection

            //Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)_activity.Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.splash)).Bitmap;//no memory exception

            using (b)
            {
                CoverIv.SetImageBitmap (b);
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: let getImage return your `Bitmap` and `CoverIv.SetImageBitmap (b);` should be called directly in your `getView()` but you are not using your `int`s are you? are you also sure about the dimensions of the pic can you say the dimension? 400*400? or higher

Comment: What do you mean with you are not using your ints? the dimension of the images is correct i am 100% sure. i don't use decodefile but i use an imageloader which calculates the samplesize and scales the images with the power of 2. just for the sake of this question i replaced the imageloader.getimage() by bitmapfactory.Decodefile

Answer (score 0):

What method `CoverIv.SetImageBitmap(b)` does? Bitmap will not be garbage collected as long as CoverIv will keep reference to it. Because it is static method, I guess that bitmap is held in static field and will never be garbage collected. Do you still have memory leak when you remove  `CoverIv.SetImageBitmap(b)`?
Please check with MAT active references to your bitmap- he will show you why bitmap is not collected.

Comment: Indeed i got no memory exception when i remove CoverIv.setImageBitmap

Comment: How can i set the image without have the memoryexception then?

Comment: I tried setting a recyclelistener to check when the viewholder goes off screen, with  OnMovedToScrapHeap(View v), then i tried to get the holder with v.tag and holder.setimagebitmap(null) but it didn't work

Comment: Please analyse  sources of CoverIv (decompile if you have just binary) and use MAT to find why CoverIv  holds memory. About MAT there is excellent video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk that will make you expert of using MAT.

does CoverIv  alwyas hold single bitmap, or more (MAT will answer that)? If single maybe it is just normal memory ussage, not memory leak?

Comment: i have tried it already but i have a macbook and i'm using xamarin so i can't use it :(

Comment: MAT can be used stand-alone. You do not need eclipse https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050846/how-do-i-run-stand-alone-eclipse-mat

Comment: I took a closer look and saw that i was wrong, it's not because of the imageview.setImageBitmap after all. I will try to install MAT once again and take a look. Thank you

Comment: It's really strange MAT shows that these bitmaps are the cause of the memoryleaks but path to GC roots shows only the bitmap itself

Comment: strange indeed. what about weak references? By default MAT excludes weak references. Something must hold this bitmap.. You could also try to analyse source code of CoverIv to find out what he does with bitmap.